# Disable debug logging of Quartz.Net in an ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, quartz.net

Using Quartz.Net 3.1.3 with an ASP.NET Core app using Serilog and I'm trying to disable debug logging of quartz because it spams the logs in a production environment.

I'm setting the following in `appsettings.json`:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "MyCompanyNameSpace": "Information",
      "Quartz": "Warning"
    }
},
```

but I can still see that is logging:

```
2021-11-02 09:49:34.025 +02:00 [DBG] Calling Execute on job MyCompany.SyncJobGroup.SyncJobA
2021-11-02 09:49:34.154 +02:00 [DBG] Trigger instruction : DeleteTrigger
2021-11-02 09:49:34.154 +02:00 [DBG] Deleting trigger
```

How can I disable it?

Comment: You can see a specific case of the same being done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877217/turn-off-debug-logging-in-quartz-net/7973019

Comment: @T.Nielsen The article is not about ASP.NET Core

Comment: I just disable Quartz logging completely when running in Debug mode by using `Quartz.Logging.LogProvider.IsDisabled = true`. It's not great, but I prefer it over the log spam.